# Processing a single frame of audio and image in FFmpeg

Tags: c, actionscript-3, audio, ffmpeg

Currently we have an implementation of FFmpeg which is triggered from an ActionScript 3 (AS3) application, via CrossBridge (formerly Flascc). In this implementation, we write the entire audio track into the CModule's memory, using malloc from the AS3 application. Once written, the application starts to process each of the image frames we would like to combine with our audio. This process begins by the AS3 application calling the CModule's `write_frame` public method.

C:
`int write_frame(struct Session *s, uint8_t *buffer, int bufferSize){}`

AS3:
`var ret:int = writeFrame(_sessionPtr, _pixelBytesPtr, _pixelBytes.length);`

Once the video output has been created, it is retrieved from the CModule to AS3 as a byte array.

With this implementation, a long duration video or audio track - the application runs out of memory (there's a memory limit within our CrossBridge sandbox environment). The largest portion of this memory is currently our audio track, as it's uncompressed PCM data (raw float values).

Ideally, we would like to write a single audio frame and video frame together, with the AS3 application writing the 1 x audio frame byte array to the CModule's memory. I have attempted to do this, by allocating the memory requirement for a single frame of audio using malloc, and then overwriting this memory, each time `write_frame` is called. However, this results in the video file containing a single frame of audio at the start of the video, and no other audio.

I'm convinced that the audio frame is being constructed correctly, but I believe this approach is conflicting with some of the code within our Muxing.c file. It's a little different to FFmpeg's example file (https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/muxing_8c-source.html), as this file has been modified by several people. Here's the methods calls from within `write_frame`:

`fill_audio_buffer(s->audio_input, s->audio_input_length, s->audio_input_index, s->audio_input_frame_size * 2, s->audio_frame_buffer);`

`retval = av_samples_alloc(converted_buffer, NULL, 2, out_samples, audio_st->codec->sample_fmt, 0);`

`out_samples = swr_convert(s->audio_swr_context, converted_buffer, out_samples (void *) &s->audio_frame_buffer, in_samples);`

`retval = write_audio_frame(s, s->oc, s->audio_st, s->audio_input_frame_size (uint16_t *) converted_buffer[0]);`

`s->audio_input_index += s->audio_input_frame_size * 2;`

Is it possible to move to procedural muxing of 1 x frame of audio and 1 x frame of image approach? Even if it's slightly slower - it'll mean we're not hold the entire audio track in memory. Any suggestions to the required approach would be great, thanks in advance!

@VC. One - The PCM data is made outside of FFmpeg and then written to the memory that FFmpeg has access to. (using malloc, and then the pointer to this address is sent to the FFmpeg).

The FFmpeg output file can either be a .WMV file, or .AVi file - the codecs WMV2 and DIVX are used in each case. I have made some modifications since posting the original question, but you're correct in thinking that the first chunk was being used and then the last frame size increased, meaning the next read of the buffer would yield nothing as it exceeded the buffer.

I've now made some progress by resetting the index `audio_input_index` back to '0' at the start of each `write_frame` call. However, i'll need to check whether this is the correct approach, as between each audio frame (1 second at 1fps), there is a slight blip/audio pop noise. In addition to this - the last few frames of audio seem to overlap, causing some of the audio to be repeated. Is it safe practice with C/FFmpeg to recycle a buffer in this way? It seems that the length of each audio frame changes - at AS3 level my current calculation of the audio frame byte length is (44,100 kHz sample rate * 8) / Frames per second. It's * 8 as it's two channel, and each float value is 4 bytes.

Thanks again for your help

Comment: Method declarations:
`void fill_audio_buffer(float *srcBuffer, int srcBufferLength, int offset, int length, float *dstBuffer){}

int write_audio_frame(struct Session *s, AVFormatContext *oc, AVStream *stream, int audioInputFrameSize, uint16_t *buffer){}`

Comment: I suggest you give a bit more information about the codecs involved. Was the PCM made from mp3 and did it need to be PCM? or can the MP3 frame bytes be extracted and sent to FFmpeg? What format audio is being output by FFmpeg? This resulting video, is that one audio chunk made from first or last PCM audio bytes (ie: has the "recycled buffer" just been overwriting the same position each time or do you move the pointer forward by **+ last frame size** before each new frame's data write?

Comment: Ok. I'm more familiar with web formats (FLV, MPEG, OGG etc). My logic was if MP3/ACC then do not decode to PCM but instead extract an MP3 or AAC frame and feed each piece to FFmpeg one at a time since those codecs already have multiple frames that make 21 to 23 m-secs of audio data each... Also if you made an AIR desktop app with Flash it could write temp files on hard disk but if browser-based then no luck but RAM. I'll look into some options for you soon.